# Creating questions from sentences

Tags: python, algorithm, nlp, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to create an algorithm that could transform sentences to questions. This is the code:

```
def sentence_to_question(arg):
    hverbs = ["is", "have", "had", "was", "could", "would", "will", "do", "did", "should", "shall", "can", "are"]
    words = arg.split(" ")
    zen_sim = (0, "", "")
    for hverb in hverbs:
        for word in words:
            similarity = SequenceMatcher(None, word, hverb).ratio()*100
            if similarity > zen_sim[0]:
                zen_sim = (similarity, hverb, word)
    if zen_sim[0] < 30:
        raise ValueError("unable to create question.")
    else:
        words.remove(zen_sim[2])
        words = " ".join(words)[0].lower() + " ".join(words)[1:]
        question = "{0} {1}?".format(zen_sim[1].capitalize(), words)
        return question
```

**Explanation**:
there is a prepared list of helping verbs, each word of the sentence is compared to the helping verb. The word that has highest similarity helping verb, will be chosen. [difflib.SequenceMatcher](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher)'s [Ratcliff/Obershep pattern recognition algorithm](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/ratcliffObershelp.html) is used to compare similarity of two strings. Although if the similarity percentage is less than 30%, I believe that there exists very low probability that user can misspell the helping verb by this much, and high probability that helping verb is not existent in the question, thus the question is not recognized. Finally, chosen helping verb is placed in the beginning of string. (I know the "algorithm" requires much more optimization).

**Testing on examples**:

```
>>> sentence_to_question("Euclid was a prominent mathematician")
'Was euclid a prominent mathematician?'
>>> sentence_to_question("Euclid waz a prominent mathematician") # does work with small typos
'Was euclid a prominent mathematician?'
>>> sentence_to_question("The company name, logo and slogan are vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design")
'Are the company name, logo and slogan vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design?'
```

Now as we know, multiple questions can be generated from a single sentence, but currently my "algorithm" can only generate single question. But what would be the most accurate method to generate questions like these? -

> **What** are vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design?
>
> **Who** was Euclid?

Note the difference between these two questions, first one has **What** as its initial verb, but the second one has **Who**.

I'm not asking for the code (although i would appreciate example), What is the most accurate method for generating multiple questions from sentence?

Thank You!

Comment: Is the input for your sample output "Vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design are what."? Your current implementation does not generate "What was Euclid?" either.

Comment: @usr2564301 when i input "The company name, logo and slogan are vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design" in the function, the output is - 'Are the company name, logo and slogan vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design?'.
I'm trying to find a way to generate multiple questions from input, such as - "What are vital elements of the house style of a company and important elements of corporate design?".

Comment: @usr2564301 makes a highly instructive comment which I think you should consider.  Rewriting your examples with variables replacing the noun phrases: given "subject verb object", you can always ask "Adverb verb object?"  The challenge is the correct selection of adverb.  In the case of example "vital elements...", the adverb is "What", in the case of 'Euclid", the adverb is "Who".  To get where you want to go, you'll either need to take the simple suggestion in usr2564301's comment, or add some semantic analysis of the objects

Comment: @danh My apologies, i couldn't completely understand usr2564301's comment, thank you for explaining. I forgot to add that to my question. As i understand the main aspect to turn sentence into question is to identify whether the word can be questioned by "who" or "what", but is this possible?

Comment: I think it's possible, but kind of a whole new can of worms.  Here's a good place to begin study:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-pl

Comment: @danh Thanks a lot! this will massively help!